# Обработка нажатия кнопок клавиатуры для нескольких форм

Tags: c#, winforms, обработка-данных

Как можно обработать нажатие клавиши (например f1) на 10 формах не используя события форм KeyDown?

Comment: По конкретнее напишите, что именно нужно?

Comment: Есть допустим форма и у нее 2 кнопки, которые при нажатии открывают по еще одной форме. И я хочу на всех 3 формах обрабатывать нажатие клавиши F1, но не используя события самих форм (по типу KeyDown) т.к если форм будет 20, то придется копировать код на каждую форму.